# Convert Array of RGB Integers to Bitmap

Tags: java, bitmap

We know that, we can get rgb of bitmap image with using the code as follow :

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(bitmapURL));
int[] pixels = img.getRGB(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null, 0, img.getWidth());
```

And, after executing this parts of code, we have an array of integers that contains 4 bytes for `Alpha, Red, Green and Blue` colors of any pixel. So, i want to know that how can we convert an array of integers like `int [] myPixels;` to Bitmap ? Could any one please help me to reach this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly use this :

```
image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
```

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(width, height);

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    im.setRGB(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note that, we have an 1D array, not 2D array! So, how can i convert it to Bitmap ?

Comment: yes, you need to calculate the correct offset in your array for the pixel you are setting

Comment: Then you should just change the code with `for(int i=0; i< width*heigth; i++) { im.setRGB(...): }`