# Convert array of RGB values into image in Android

Tags: java, android, rgb, android-bitmap

I have converted a JPEG image to an array of RGB color values through `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` and this code:

```
picw = selectedImage.getWidth();
pich = selectedImage.getHeight();

int[] pix = new int[picw * pich];

selectedImage.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);
int R, G, B;

for (int y = 0; y < pich; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < picw; x++) {
            int index = y * picw + x;
            R = (pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff;
            G = (pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
            B = pix[index] & 0xff;
            pix[index] = (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
        }
    }
```

Now, how do I convert this array back into an image?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert-array-of-rgb-integers-to-bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728047/convert-array-of-rgb-integers-to-bitmap)

Comment: @Venugopal setRGB is no in android

Answer (score 6):

you can use the static method [Bitmap.createBitmap](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(int[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config)). E.g.

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(pix, picw, pich, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
```